# Magento - How to keep URL parameters for links on the page

Tags: php, apache, magento, nginx

I have a static page on my website with parameters e.g. `example.com/abc.html?param=1`. Now, this page has some **hrefs** in it for other pages.

```
e.g. `example.com/cd.html , example.com/folder/xyz.html`
```

How can I dynamically add the param of the URL to all the hrefs on the page?

```
e.g. example.com/cd.html?param=1
```

Comment: You'll probably need to use JavaScript to add the parameters to all hyperlinks once the DOM has loaded

Comment: By the way, are you using Apache or Nginx? Presume it's not both...

Comment: Apache solution will be better...that way I am not worried about changing it on different pages.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the $_GET array which will contain all the parameters in it and you can simple append it where need

Comment: content on the page comes from different CMS pages and I dont have control over it.

Comment: This is bad practice in Magento

Comment: My bad..I meant to say CMS blocks. Page contains many cms blocks which will have hrefs in it.